# register variable

Tags: magento

I'm have following problem,
I dont know it's a good way, In list.phtml on the grid section I'm added
...

```
<?php Mage::register('listgridproduct', $_product); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('data_list_grid'); ?>
<?php Mage::unregister('listgridproduct'); ?>
```

earlier I'm define this block in catalog.xml section

```
<!--
Category layered navigation layout
-->
<block type="stock/listgrid" name="data_list_grid" template="stock/listgrid.phtml"/>
```

My block class

```
class Tim_Stock_Block_Listgrid extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {            
    public function getProductId(){            
        $id=Mage::registry('listgridproduct')->getId();               
        var_dump($id);
    }        
}
```

after execute the script on the grid the block display Id of first product for all product.
[image]
thx for help

Comment: Ok and whats your problem?

Comment: the block print id of first product, but in the theory the block should print id of next product, because grid/list section generate product in foreach, and after <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('data_list_grid'); ?> I'm unregister variable. I wonder when is mistake,

Comment: I'm resolved the problem, instead the code above I'm use  a <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('stock/listgrid')->setData('key',$_product->getId())->setTemplate('stock/listgrid.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>